# Response from node app returns nothing, but should return array

Tags: node.js, express

I am testing a nodeJS server, built on the express framework.

When a request is sent to the server, the server should send back some data, in the form of an array.  Instead, it is sending back `''`.

The test that I am trying to pass is as follows:

```
it('should send postgres data to the server', function(done) {
  request(app)
  .post('/chart')
  .send({min:"1",max:"100",arrayLength:"12"})
  .expect(200, sqlData)
  .end(function(err, res){
    if(err) {
      done(err);
    } else {
      done();
    }
  });
});
```

Note that sqlData is equal to what the sent response should be.

When the router receives a POST request it does the following:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(randomSqlTableSelector(req.body.min,req.body.max,req.body.arrayLength));
});
```

I have checked that req.body.min, max and arrayLength are all the numbers that I would expect them to be.

Thus, the problem is likely in my function `randomSqlTableSelector`, which, for whatever reason, when called inside of the router, simple returns the empty quotes `''`

The function is as follows:

```
function randomSqlTableSelector(min,max,arrayLength) {
    var filledArray = [];
    pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT cell1 FROM random AS retrievedNumber;', function(err, result) {
            var psqlData = result.rows;
            for (i in psqlData) {
                filledArray.push(psqlData[i]["cell1"])
            }
            return filledArray
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is happening because your database connection stuff is asynchronous, so your randomSql function is actually returning before you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot treat functions that perform asynchronous, non-blocking tasks as synchronous and blocking. Try passing in a callback instead:

```
function randomSqlTableSelector(min, max, arrayLength, cb) {
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    if (err)
      return cb(err);
    client.query('SELECT cell1 FROM random AS retrievedNumber;', function(err, result) {
      if (err)
        return cb(err);
      var psqlData = result.rows,
          filledArray = [],
          i;
      for (i in psqlData)
        filledArray.push(psqlData[i]["cell1"])
      cb(null, filledArray);
    });
  });
}
```

Then use it in your route like:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var min = req.body.min,
      max = req.body.max,
      len = req.body.arrayLength;
  randomSqlTableSelector(min, max, len, function(err, array) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.send(500);
    }
    res.send(array);
  });
});
```